# angular ng-click ou javascript evento click dentro do HTML SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do an implementation with SweetAlert2 where create some buttons inside the property "html". This is within a click function which in turn is within a Controller.

I tried to add in a setTimeOut () and within the $ apply () as code below:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        swal({
            title: "Lançamento por Código",
            width: 400,
            html: "" +
            "   <div>" +
            "       <input type='button' id='btn0' name='btn0' value='0' />" +
            "   </div>" +
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#FFB200",
            cancelButtonColor: "#FFB200",
            colorHoverButton: "#5B2E90",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirmar",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            reverseButtons: true,
            input: "text"
        }).then(function () {

        });
    })
},0);
```

For this button I created, I try to create a click event as the code below:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $("input[name='btn0']").on("click", function () {
            $scope.valorLancProduto += "0";
            $('.swal2-input').val($scope.valorLancProduto);
        });
    })
},0);
```

I tried to put the same into the init () function and a click function. My problem arises now, click this event is not working, it is not called. How can I solve this?

Comment: English `required()`

Answer (score 0):

Can change the call from my onclick event, was as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn0", function () {
```

Thanks.